# How to fit div to edge of screen for smaller screens?

Tags: html, css

How do I make a div section that needs to fill an entire window for smaller screens? narrow is the div section (this is like a card). syllabus (or FAQs as you will see in the screenshot) is the page. syllabus.narrow is the specific narrow card for the syllabus page, but that's not important.

[image]

I need the white card to spread out to the edges of the screen (sides of screen, and to the bottom of the header). I need it to center automatically. Changing the margins/padding doesn't keep it centered for all screen sizes.

This is the default css for narrow.

```
.narrow {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

This is the css for smaller screens.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .syllabus {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .syllabus.narrow {
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 5px;
    }
}
```

This is the html code for the page.

```
<div id="{{ page.title }}" class="offset">
  <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top:5px;">
    <div class="syllabus narrow" style="margin-top: -25px;">
      <div class="card bg-white rounded shadow-sm py-5 py-4">
        {{ content }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [viewport-relative width `vw`](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/), by setting:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .syllabus {
      width: 100vw;
    }

    .syllabus.narrow {
      width: 100vw;
      padding-top: 5px;
    }
}
```

This will allow the individual element(s) to expand past the width of their container, and occupy the full viewport width. Note that they will still be *positioned* the same way, so you'll likely also want to set a `margin-left` that sets them back to their original position, or alternatively set `position: absolute`.

Other than this, you would need to ensure that the parent (and any other ancestor) is full-width, and then make use of `width: 100%`.

Answer (score 0):

You have given 100% width to the parent div with class "narrow".

but for its child div with class "card", you have'nt set `width: 100%`

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .syllabus.narrow .card{
      width: 100%; 
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      padding-top: 5px;
    }
}
```